# Out of curiosity is there a way to use compilation symbols on a single statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I am adding debug statements in a few places in my code.
Each time I use a boolean to know if I should be debugging. This boolean is a property that checks a few unerlying conditions.
To avoid unecessary boolean checks in the actual release build, I am also adding a compilation symbol.

```
#if MY_DEBUG
            if (IsDebugging) {
               ...
            }
#endif
```

Is there are way to somehow merge both if on one line without needing the #endif at the end? Something that would look somewhat like this:

```
#if MY_DEBUG if (IsDebugging) {
               ...
            }
```

EDIT:
Thank you @canton7 I didn't know about the ConditionalAttribute
`[Conditional("MY_DEBUG")]`

I think this is what I was looking for

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, that's a bit of a red flag for me anyway. Debug code should be as close to release code as possible.

Comment: "Each time I use a boolean to know if I should be debugging." - [just use `Debugger.IsAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Note that you can also put [`[Conditional("MY_DEBUG")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-6.0) on a suitable *method*, and then call that method lots. The entire method and all of the calls to it will be removed if `MY_DEBUG` isn't set. This is what [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Debug.cs,133) does for instance -- all calls to `Debug.WriteLine` are simply compiled out if `DEBUG` isn't set

Comment: "To avoid unecessary boolean checks in the actual release build" Really? *That's* your bottleneck?